# Limiting android GPS tracking, but limiting data collection to a very specific geographic region and when the phone is in motion

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, battery

I'm creating an Android app that tracks users movements in a specific region for research purposes (and yes, the user will specifically consent to this overt tracking, and be able to turn it off if they want). I need quite high resolution spatial data, so I will need to use the GPS sensor quite frequently.

The region I want to collect data in is approximately rectangular, around 1 km (0.6 miles) x 1.5 km (0.9 miles). I would like the best possible resolution of spatial data when the user is in motion within this zone (probably 10 m spatial data, sampled every 20 seconds or so). Because I care about spatial behaviour on the edge of the study site, I am considering adding a 0.5 km buffer around the site.

Of course, I want to minimise my apps battery use. In particular, there are two scenarios in which I do not want to store any location data at all:

1. When the user is stationary (on-site or off-site); or
2. When the user is off-site

Unfortunately, detecting whether or not the user is off-site will require polling the location service! I want to mode switch between no collection (stationary), infrequent low-resolution collection (off-site) and frequent high-resolution collection (on-site) modes (see the image).

**How should I implement this protocol while conserving battery life using Android APIs? Which APIs should I target?**

[image: Data collection modes]

Comment: Would you please specify your desired accuracy in meters, what is the diameter of your region. When crossing the border of the region after how many meters you need a reaction? 10, 50, 1000m?

Comment: Hi @AlexWien I've updated the question with more info about the spatial characteristics of the region

Answer (score 1):

have you already considered on checking whether com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence woulkd give you good enough battery usage ?

Comment: I suspect using a geofence will help me to implement my mode switching, but I do not know how to ensure that battery usage is minimised.

Comment: Its platform API, and there is at least one place: http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps which is mentioning that it is at least now better on Battery sense than before.

Comment: Also, you could yourself, monitor movement with sensors, and then use coarse location first to detect whether they are near enough to you to use GPS. anyway, I would bet the original suggestion would work easier and more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

For your required resolution you need that GPS (GPS_PROVIDER) is used nearby the campus.
First start to always use GPS_PROVIDER.
Once everything works improve:

Next step is to try to save battery   by switching on the high quality GPS_PROVIDER mode only when the device is near the campus.
For that task you could specify an additional buffer rectangle 1.5 - 2km outside the  campus rectangle.
This buffer rectangle is the trigger to enable the high quality GPS mode.
while outside of the rectangle try to use NETWORK_PROVIDER.
Experiment which accuracy you get using the NETWORK_PROVIDER specific to the campus.
Expect 1km. therefore i recommedn the addional buffer of 1.5 - 2km.